# Cant get Nativescript plugin to work "nativescript-admob"

Tags: javascript, android, admob, google-play-services, nativescript

I have installed prerequisite "Google play service" in SDK Manager Extras. when run, App page shows up on emulator without banner and CLI log shows error. could any one tell me what am I missing?

```
    admob.createBanner({
        // if this 'view' property is not set, the banner is overlayed on the current top most view
        // view: ..,
        testing: true, // set to false to get real banners
        size: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER, // anything in admob.AD_SIZE, like admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER
        iosBannerId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXX/YYYYYY", // add your own
        androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-9495738740700511/5085446949", // add your own
        // Android automatically adds the connected device as test device with testing:true, iOS does not
        iosTestDeviceIds: ["yourTestDeviceUDIDs", "EAA5B49DBA3AD30CC27A343C86CD7ADF"],
        margins: {
          // if both are set, top wins
          //top: 10
          bottom: 50
        }
      }).then(
          function() {
            console.log("admob createBanner done");
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log("admob createBanner error: " + error);
          }
    )
```

1. I have created new project "tns create adtest"
2. added plugin "tns plugin add nativescript-admob"
3. added platform "tns platform add android"
4. running by "tns livesync android --watch"

---ERROR LOG---

```
Project successfully prepared
The application with id "org.nativescript.adtest" is not installed on device with identifier emulator-5554.
Project successfully prepared
WARNING: The file: D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\node_modules\nativescript-admob\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml is depricated, you can read more about what will be the expected plugin structure here: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-n-android-plugins-from-version-1.7-to-2.0

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: nativescript-admob
 {
              "F0" {
                dimension "nativescriptadmob"
              }
            }
}       +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
 {
            "F1" {
              dimension "tnscoremoduleswidgets"
            }
          }
        }
:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\platforms\android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\platforms\android\configurations\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-admob\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets\include.gradle

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: D:\GoogleDrive\PROJECTS\adtest\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preF0F1DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkF0F1DebugManifest
:preF0F1ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary
:prepareF0F1DebugDependencies
:compileF0F1DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0F1DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:cleanLocalAarFiles
:ensureMetadataOutDir
:collectAllJars
:setProperties
:asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList
:asbg:runAstParser UP-TO-DATE
:asbg:generateBindings UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1DebugAssets
:generateF0F1DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processF0F1DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processF0F1DebugResources
:generateF0F1DebugSources
:compileF0F1DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0F1DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0F1DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:buildMetadata UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexForF0F1Debug UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1DebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForF0F1Debug UP-TO-DATE
:processF0F1DebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForF0F1Debug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageF0F1Debug
:zipalignF0F1Debug
:assembleF0F1Debug
:assembleDebug
:deleteExplodedAarFolder UP-TO-DATE
:buildapk

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.657 secs
Project successfully built
JS: Treating this deviceId as testdevice: CA5F7DA5D57FD0D05E676D0CD880FB80
chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
05-06 03:27:04.304  3124  3124 I BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
05-06 03:27:04.349  3124  3124 E DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
JS: Error in admob.createBanner: TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of null
JS: admob createBanner error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of null
chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Creating Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Downloading event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (0 of 4) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.js", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (1 of 4) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/production/sdk-core-v40-impl.js", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (2 of 4) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/canary/sdk-core-v40-impl.js", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (3 of 4) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/native_ads.js", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggest would be simply to use tns android debug. That way you can see what causes this error:
Cannot read property 'android' of null

Seems to me like you are call admob too early and not everything has been initialized. Anyway, simply debug it :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's correct, maybe to early. I have placed it in page navigatingTo function and maybe doesn't have enough time to initialize. When I move it in TAP button it simply works on click. But my problem is now I want to load it when page starts. Does Nativescript has something like on pageload or whats best way to position it?

Comment: Of course. Just check their documentation https://docs.nativescript.org/. Faster than posting on SO ;)

Comment: <Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">  and of course then your exported function should be pageLoaded